# Writing a prototype function(c++)

Tags: c++, function

I have to write the prototype and the implementation of a C++ function that
receives a character and returns true if the character is a vowel and false otherwise. Vowels
include uppercase and lowercase of the following characters ‘a’. ‘e’, ‘i’, ‘o’ and ‘u’.

I have written

```
bool vowelOrNot(char x)
{   if(x="a" or "e" or "i" or "o" or "u")
       cout<<"true"<<endl;

    else
       cout<<"false""<<endl;
}
```

i wrote or cause i dont know how to do the lines on here, am i correct on my function?

Comment: You want an answer as if this was pseudo code or as if this was c++ ?

Comment: That's not valid C++. `or` isn't a keyword (look at `||`) and you don't test for equality using `=` (look at `==`). Also, your function is suppose to return a `bool` but you don't return anything.

Comment: I would use a switch statement for this.

Comment: The function is incorrect as either C++ or pseudo code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bool vowelOrNot(char x) //x must be lowercase for the function to work as expected
{   if(x=='a' || x=='e' || x=='i' || x=='o' ||  x=='u' ) //== for comparing and single quotes for a char.
   //|| is the logical OR
   {
       cout<<"true"<<endl;
       return true; //return true to function caller
   }
    else
       cout<<"false"<<endl;
   return false;//return false to function caller
}
```

Comment: i know the or signs, but how do i write them on my keyboard? any help? and should the cout statements be in this function or the main function since all i need to do within this function is return true or flase.

Comment: @user3531022 , The button above the enter key? And `cout` dosen't matter if it is placed in here or in `main`. If in `main`,use `cout<<"function returned "<<vowelOrNot(yourchar);`

Comment: @user3531022 shift + \ for me

Comment: @user3531022 On my keyboard it's `AltGr + <`.

Answer (score 3):

As no one suggested it, here is a solution using a switch statement:

```
bool vowelOrNot(char x)
{
    switch (x)
    {
        case 'a':
        case 'A':
        case 'e':
        case 'E':
        case 'i':
        case 'I':
        case 'o':
        case 'O':
        case 'u':
        case 'U':
            return true;

        default:
            return false;
    }
}
```

I considered using `toupper` to convert input and only check capitals in the case.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a test, e.g.,

```
int
main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
   bool test1 = vowelOrNot ( 'a' );
   std::cout << test1 << " expected to be true" << std::endl;

   return test1 == true ? EXIT_SUCCESS : EXIT_FAILURE;    
}
```

Of course, the test isn't complete. But you have to write the test for all possible input data.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with the use of the word prototype.  A C++ function prototype is a declaration that usually occurs at the top of a file before main() or in a header file of a module (probably the former in your case).  It would look like this:

```
bool vowelOrNot(char);
```

What you have is the implementation, but you have incorrect syntax.  "or" is not a keyword in C++.  Use "||".  Also, "==" is the equal-to comparison operator rather than "=".  I recommend reviewing at least the following documentation: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/control/.

Also, I noticed that your function returns a boolean, yet you are printing the word for each boolean value rather than returning it.  If you need to print those words, it should be handled elsewhere based on the return value of the function.

The solution I recommend is as follows:

```
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

bool vowelOrNot(char);

const string VOWELS = "aeiou";

int main
{
    //some code that uses vowelOrNot, perhaps printing true and false
}

bool vowelOrNot(char c)
{
  return VOWELS.find(tolower(c)) != string::npos;
}
```

Finally, I recommend renaming the function to is_vowel() or something like that to be more clear and concise about the function's purpose.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
    bool vowelOrNot(char x)
    {   if(x=='a' || x=='e' || x=='i' || x=='o' || x=='u' || x=='A' || x=='E' || x=='I' || x=='O' || x=='U')
         {
           cout<<"true"<<endl;
           return true;
          }

        else
        {
           cout<<"false"<<endl;
           return false;
        }
    }
```